# Фильтрация и преобразование массива. Vanilla js

Tags: javascript

Задача простая, в функцию приходит `id` и `type`. Мне необходимо из объекта value убрать значение `type`, т.е мне необходимо преобразовать массив. Я использую `.map`, я делаю проверку на `id`,а потом в объекте `value` убираю type.На выходе должен получится новый массив, без `type`.

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
  { id: 2, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
  { id: 3, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
  { id: 4, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя"] }
];

let id = 1;
let type = "Маленькая";

console.log(
  data.map((z) => {
    if (z.id === id) {
      let arr = z.value.filter((p) => p !== type);
      z.value = [arr];
    }
  })
);
```

На выходе я получаю `[null,null,null,null]`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: "Что я делаю не так?" --- как минимум вы не прочли документацию по map в которой написано что колбэк должен что-то возвращать....

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения.
**MAP** возвращает уже **НОВЫЙ** массив.
Так что выводить в консоль нужно именно результат выполнения этого метода.
Не стоит забывать, что если в условии мы попали на другой ID, то **Z** также нужно возвращать.

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
    { id: 2, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
    { id: 3, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
    { id: 4, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя"] }
];

let id = 1;
let type = "Маленькая";

data = data.map(z => {
    if (z.id === id) {
       z.value = z.value.filter(val => val != type);
    }
    return z;
})

console.log(data)
```

Вывод:

```
[
  { id: 1, value: [ 'Средняя', 'Большая' ] },
  { id: 2, value: [ 'Маленькая', 'Средняя', 'Большая' ] },
  { id: 3, value: [ 'Маленькая', 'Средняя', 'Большая' ] },
  { id: 4, value: [ 'Маленькая', 'Средняя' ] }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
  { id: 2, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
  { id: 3, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя", "Большая"] },
  { id: 4, value: ["Маленькая", "Средняя"] }
];

let id = 1;
let type = "Маленькая";

console.log(
  data.map((z) => {
    if (z.id === id) {
    return  z.value = [...z.value.filter((p) => p !== type)];
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Это ответ на ваш вопрос?)

Comment: @Jour да, я думал что `return` не нужен

Comment: @Frallen тогда не хватает ещё одного return, когда в if не попадёт (причём именно этого ретёрна будет и достаточно, а не того, что в if)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский верно, но мне не нужен возврат в случае не совпадения id

Comment: @Frallen тогда тут map не нужен, а нужен один filter..... в ином случае у тебя получается `[
  [
    "Средняя",
    "Большая"
  ],
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined
]`